# Haskell - if else return clean tuple

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

My homework task is to group two tuples in a list if the second element of the first tuple is the same as the first element of the second tuple. Then, if the first tuple is `(a, b)` and the second is `(b, c)`, the tuple `(a, c)` must be added to the result list.

I wrote first function wich takes element with one tuple and second list with many tuples and compare each to each.

this one works correcly:

```
c1 = ("a","x")
d1 = [ ("x","b"), ("z","c"), ("x","b"), ("z","c")
     , ("x","b"), ("z","c"), ("x","b"), ("z","c") ]

getByOne c1 a1 = filter (/=[])
  [ if (fst  (last(take n a1))) == (snd c1)
    then [((fst c1),  (snd  (last(take n a1))))]
    else  [] | n <- [1..(length a1) ] ]
```

output:

```
[ [("a","b")], [("a","b")], [("a","b")], [("a","b")] ]
```

But the problems is that I can't throw in if then and else  statement just simple tuple, so I create a new list. In the end of this "workaround" i am getting list in list in list and so on. Also if output list was bigger, there were be more lists in lists.

Is there any way to pass out only tuple or empty tuple or i should somehow group theses lists ?

Comment: But this isn't the output that you _want_, right? What output _do_ you want, it's not clear to me.

Comment: Well, I will try to solve this task by my self as far it is a part from my homework. Thx again for helping.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can flatten the result using

```
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
```

then you don't even need to `filter (/=[])` - by the way, the condition `(/= [])` is more idiomatically written `not . null`, since the `null` test doesn't impose an `Eq` constraint on its argument (you already have one here, so it's just a matter of idiom).

Further, `last (take n a1)` is just the `n`-th element of `a1` if `1 <= n <= length a1`. Since you have that restriction imposed, that can more succinctly be expressed as `a1 !! (n-1)`

Then you have structurally

```
getByOne c1 a1 = concat $ [something c1 (a1 !! i) | i <- [0 .. length a1 - 1]]
```

(I have shifted indices to index by `i`), which is clearer and more efficiently expressed as

```
getByOne c1 a1 = concat $ map (something c1) a1
```

If you prefer a list comprehension to `map`, you can also write that as

```
getByOne c1 a1 = concat [something c1 x | x <- a1]
```

which in your case, using the ability to pattern-match in alist-comprehension generator, gives us

```
getByOne (f,s) a1 = concat [ if a == s then [(f,b)] else [] | (a,b) <- a1]
```

which is much shorter and more readable. Instead of using `if condition then [element] else []` and `concat`, even nicer is to use a condition in the list comprehension,

```
getByOne (f,s) list = [(f,b) | (a,b) <- list, a == s]
```

which is short and clear.

Comment: +1 Seeing stuff like this reminds me how readable Haskell code can be the resulting function is clearer and shorter than a verbal description.

Comment: concat :: [[a]] -> [a] very useful in this case.

Answer (score 3):

1. `[1..(length a1)]` can be written `[1 .. length a1]`
2. ```
   [ if (fst  (last(take n a1))) == (snd c1)
     then [((fst c1),  (snd  (last(take n a1))))]
     else  [] | n <- [1..(length a1) ] ]
   ```

   can be written

   ```
   [ if fst lastElement == snd c1
     then [(fst c1, snd lastElement)]
     else [] | n <- [1 .. length a1 ]
             , let lastElement = last (take n a1) ]
   ```
3. Then, instead of using the list index to go through it, use the list directly:

   ```
   [ if x == snd c1
     then [(fst c1, y)]
     else [] | (x, y) <- a1 ]
   ```
4. Then, instead of using a list to represent the existence or not of a solution, use `Maybe`:

   ```
   import Data.Maybe

   c1 = ("a","x")
   d1 = [ ("x","b"), ("z","c"), ("x","b"), ("z","c")
        , ("x","b"), ("z","c"), ("x","b"), ("z","c") ]

   getByOne c1 a1 = catMaybes
           [ if x == snd c1
             then Just (fst c1, y)
             else Nothing | (x, y) <- a1 ]
   ```
5. Better yet, use a guard and get rid of the if then else:

   ```
   getByOne (a, b) a1 = [ (a, d) | (c, d) <- a1
                                 , b == c ]
   ```

Alternatively, if you want to use filter, you first filter the list of matching tuples, then build the corresponding results with map:

```
getByOne (a, b) a1 = map (\(_, c) -> (a, c))
                     . filter (\(c, _) -> b == c)
                     $ a1
```

which simplifies into

```
getByOne (a, b) = map (\(_, c) -> (a, c))
                     . filter (\(c, _) -> b == c)
```

Comment: use of `[]` entries under `concat` is quite idiomatic to express elimination (filtering), and `if-the-else` can further be replaced with another comprehension, in your `#3`: `[[(fst c1, y) | snd c1==x] | (x, y) <- a1 ]`, directly simplifying to your `#5`. :)